# What is this "sprocket" called?

Tags: technical, image-identification

I wonder what the "sprocket" in this image is called, since I cannot find anything like it when I searching for sprocket in an online shop like www.grainger.com or globalindustrial.com.

Is there a specific definition for it?

[image: Sprocket wheel]

Comment: General English doesn't have specific terms for specialized kinds of gears. You'd have to ask on a relevant engineering forum.

Comment: As @DanBron suggests, try e.g. our sister site, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way, the correct way to ask the question is *what* is it called, not *how* is it called. This seems to be a common mistake of non-native speakers.

Comment: Chain sprocket or chainring.

Comment: It's a *sprocket*. And probably not a bicycle sprocket, as the configuration is wrong on several points.

Answer (score 4):

I am unsure if you are looking for a general term, or a description of the actual sprocket in the picture.

The one in the picture is a ***rear sprocket*** , specifically a [428 sprocket](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/428-sprocket), a 48T (tooth)  4-bolt rear sprocket for a small motorcycle or moped, possibly a Honda Passport. ***428*** refers to the [specifications of the chain required](http://www.gizmology.net/sprockets.htm) for the sprocket design.

Answer (score 1):

It’s called a **chainwheel**. They’re found on bicycles and motorcycles, but the term is used generally.

Here’s a link to a commercial supplier: https://www.babbitt.com/chainwheels/

Comment: Maybe you mean “chainring” not chainwheel.  None of the chainwheels in your link look remotely like the chainring OP has shown.

Comment: The OP is looking for a general term.  A general term applies to multiple specific items, which are alike in certain properties, but not in all.  A chainring may be part of a chainwheel, but this is like a tire being part of a wheel. We speak of two-wheel drive and four-wheel drive, even though (strictly speaking) it’s the tires that touch the road.